# What are the non-numeric IRQs in /proc/interrupts?

Tags: linux-kernel, proc, interrupt, irq

`cat /proc/interrupts` shows a bunch of IRQs such as `NMI` and `LOC`. The per-line comments in the output give clear explanation, but if they do not have a numeric IRQ number, how does the x86 CPU respond to them, in terms of entries in the Interrupt Descriptor Table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-numeric entries in `/proc/interrupts` correspond to arch-specific, non-device-related interrupts.

On x86, the IDT layout is described in [`arch/x86/include/asm/irq_vectors.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/irq_vectors.h):

> - Vectors   0 ...  31 : system traps and exceptions - hardcoded events
> - Vectors  32 ... 127 : device interrupts
> - Vector  128         : legacy int80 syscall interface
> - Vectors 129 ... LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR-1
> - Vectors LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR ... 255 : special interrupts

The arch-specific interrupts are handled by IDT entries from 0 to 31 and from 129 to 255, with the local timer interrupt the first in the latter range. So when you see 0 in `/proc/interrupts`, it’s IDT entry 32; when you see NMI, it’s entry 2; etc. The IDT itself is set up in [`arch/x86/kernel/idt.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/idt.c).

Comment: Thanks. I also found this file gives enumeration of system traps and exceptions `/arch/x86/include/asm/traps.h`. So does that mean that a standard linux on x86 can only support 127 - 31 = 96 external device interrupts? (I peeked into the same file on google's pixelbook and saw IRQs 201 for intel gpio and 207 for iwlwifi)

Comment: The IDT has been reworked several times; I described the current setup. Your Pixelbook might have been running an older kernel — in the past, fewer special interrupts were reserved, and device interrupts could go up to 200+. There are only 96 device interrupt entries in the IDT now, but that doesn’t limit the external device support much; PCI can share interrupts, the kernel supports hierarchical IRQ domains, etc.